# Open a shared calendar that is not a Default Calendar in Outlook 2013

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I know this question has been sort of asked, but I have a specific issue which I haven't found the answer for. I am trying to open a shared calendar from another user and his/her calendar is NOT their default calendar.

I have tried the following:

```
    var ns = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session;

    var recip = ns.CreateRecipient("me@me.com");
    if (recip.Resolve())
    {
      var sharedCal = ns.GetSharedDefaultFolder(recip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
    }
```

This just does not work.

I can see the shared calendar by doing the following

```
private void GetCalendars()
        {

            Outlook.CalendarModule calModule = (Outlook.CalendarModule)this.Application.ActiveExplorer().NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(Outlook.OlNavigationModuleType.olModuleCalendar);


            foreach (Outlook.NavigationGroup group in calModule.NavigationGroups)

            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Calandar Folders Group  >>>>" + group.Name);


                foreach (Outlook.NavigationFolder folder in group.NavigationFolders)
                {

                    Debug.WriteLine("Calandar Folders:  >>>>" + folder.DisplayName);

                }
            }
        }
```

I just don't know how to open the calendar once I have the name. There is no way to get the ID using the steps above

In outlook, the calendar exists in the "Shared Calendars" navigation tree.

I am looking for a way to get the names of the Shared Calendars and then having the user select the shared calendar (E.g. From a dropdown box) and then opening that calendar.

I have found code on how to do everything else but not that specifically!

Can someone point me in the right direction??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access that folder using the Outlook Object Model.

For a cached Exchange mailbox, the folders are cached n the primary mailbox's OST file. On the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi), the folders are stored outside of the IPM tree visible to the end user. You can see the data in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - click IMsgStore | Open Root Folder | GetHierarchyTable | double click on the "Shared Data" folder | GetHierarchyTable | etc.

You can open that folder using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am also its author - start with [RDOStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm).RootFolder). You can also open the online mailbox of another user using [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).GetSharedMailbox and navigate to the folder in question starting with [RDOStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm).IPMRootFolder (returns top level folders visible to the user in that mailbox).

Comment: OK. I am now using the redemption libs. How do I get a list of all the shared calendars that are displayed under "Shared Calendars"

Comment: You can enumerate all subfolders of the "Shared Data" folder (that will give you recipients), then look for a folder named Calendar. I am pretty sure Outlook maps user vs folder kind vs actual fodler, but I was never able to find where the mapping is stored.

Comment: Can you please give me a sample on how to do this? Thanks :-)

Comment: rFolder = Session.Stores.DefaultStore.RootFolder.Folders("Shared Data").Folders("First Last").Folders("Calendar")

Comment: Hi Dmitry. There are no items under the Shared Data folder. The item count is 0;

Comment: What do you see in OutlookSpy? Are you looking at the GetHierarchyTable or GetContentsTable tab?

Comment: These are the steps. Select "Shared Folders" Then IMsgStore | Open Root Container| GetHierarchyTable | Double Click "Shared Folder" | GetHierarchyTable

Comment: So there no folders on the Shared Data | GetHierarchyTable tab?

Comment: Yes. That comes up with nothing.

Comment: Is "Download shared folders" checkbox checked on the Advanced tab of the Exchange account properties dialog?